# special character file seen after inserting brand new drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I am using the following kernel in my server (4.4.0-31-generic) and i see the below issue, when i am replacing a drive.

I see the following character device file, after the new drive is inserted. I dont see this file,  when the old drive is removed. (I make sure all IOs to the drive is stopped, before i remove)

```
    brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 128 Jul 24 19:07 /dev/sdi 
    cr-------- 1 root root 8, 129 Jul 15 23:50 /dev/sdi1     =====> (Who creates with this permissions, i have seen this only in pseudo terminals)
```

At the same time, i see entries for this partition in /proc/diskstats and /sys/class/block.

```
    /proc/diskstats

       8     128 sdi 139089 4 2112504 37000 4473 31 312 9212 0 30764 46144
       8     129 sdi1 21056 0 241392 9308 0 0 0 0 0 8928 9292


    cat /sys/class/block/sdi1/start 
    2048
    cat /sys/class/block/sdi1/size
    15628048384
```

$ stat /dev/sdi1

```
      File: ‘/dev/sdi1’
      Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
    Device: 6h/6d    Inode: 723         Links: 1     Device type: 8,81 
    Access: (0400/cr--------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
    Access: 2017-07-15 23:50:00.675853644 +0000
    Modify: 2017-07-15 23:50:00.675853644 +0000
    Change: 2017-07-15 23:50:00.675853644 +0000
```

Birth: -

$ stat /dev/sdi

```
      File: ‘/dev/sdi’
      Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
  Device: 6h/6d    Inode: 521         Links: 1     Device type: 8,80
  Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    6/    disk)
  Access: 2017-07-25 23:37:22.598418068 +0000
  Modify: 2017-07-25 23:37:22.598418068 +0000
  Change: 2017-07-25 23:37:22.598418068 +0000
```

Birth: -

Has anyone seen something similar. Who could possibly have created such a file, with block attributes, but a character file.

```
    N: sdi
    S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:09:00.0-sas-0x5000cca23bd280a5-lun-0
    E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdi
    E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:09:00.0/host0/port-0:0/expander-0:0/port-0:0:13/end_device-0:0:13/target0:0:13/0:0:13:0/block/sdi
    E: DEVTYPE=disk
    E: ID_BUS=scsi
    E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=gpt
    E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:09:00.0-sas-0x5000cca23bd280a5-lun-0
    E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_09_00_0-sas-0x5000cca23bd280a5-lun-0
    E: ID_REVISION=A7D8
    E: ID_SCSI=1
    E: ID_SCSI_SERIAL=2EKRSUZV
    E: ID_TYPE=disk
    E: MAJOR=8
    E: MINOR=128
    E: SUBSYSTEM=block
    E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4744118623
    E: nomdmonddf=1
    E: nomdmonisw=1
```

Comment: Look at the system log files! `journalctl -b` will show everything since last boot.